# Converted ASP.net 4.0 site to 4.5 but some files still remains as 4.0 are they correct?

Tags: asp.net, web, web-config, asp.net-4.5

Converted ASP.net 4.0 site to 4.5 but some files still remains as 4.0 are they correct ?

Used visual studio 2012

Here my config.xml. Do you see anything incorrect ? 
System.web , system.design, system.windows.fomrs still 4.0 ?

When publishing i am disabling debug as false. Also thrust level what does it do ? Should i remove it ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

      <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web">
      <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false"
               type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>

  <system.web>

    <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="60"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <trust level="Full" />

    <sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"></add>
      </providers>
    </sanitizer>

    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <pages validateRequest="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="true" enableSessionState="true" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
    <httpModules/>

  </system.web>


  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"/>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true"/>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. Not every framework library is enhanced with new versions of .NET. So, if nothing was added to the reference library then it keeps the old version.

Comment: - You might have to toggle runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to "true" if you have any custom routing or handlers, and the reference to System.Windows.Forms seems completely out of place for a website (unless your using that hacky webbrowser control to create page images code)

Comment: i am composing security question images. simple ones though. so it must be the reason why included D: